# Extract characters from a long string and reformat the output to CSV by using keywords with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, parsing, string

I am new to VB.Net 2008. I have a task to resolve, it is regading extracting characters from a long string to the console, the extracted text shall be reformatted and saved into a CSV file. The string comes out of a database.

It looks something like: `UNH+RAM6957+ORDERS:D:96A:UN:EGC103'BGM+38G::ZEW+REQEST6957+9'DTM+Z05:0:805'DTM+137:20100930154`

The values are seperated by `'`.

I can query the database and display the string on the console, but now I need to extract the
Keyword `'ORDERS'` for example, and lets say it's following 5 Characters. So the output should look like: `ORDERS:D:96A` then I need to extract the keyword `'BGM'` and its following five characters so the output should look like: `BGM+38G:`

After extracting all the keywords, the result should be comma seperated and look like:

`ORDERS:D:96A,BGM+38G:` it should be saved into a CSV file automatically.

I tried already:

```
'Lookup for containing KeyWords
                    Dim FoundPosition1 = p_EDI.Contains("ORDERS")
                    Console.WriteLine(FoundPosition1)
```

Which gives the starting position of the Keyword.

I tried to trim the whole thing around the keyword "DTM". The EDI variable holds the entire string from the Database:

```
Dim FoundPosition2 = EDI
                    FoundPosition2 = Trim(Mid(EDI, InStr(EDI, "DTM")))
                    Console.WriteLine(FoundPosition2)
```

Can someone help please?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the steps involved:

```
' Find the position where ORDERS is in the string.'
Dim foundPosition = EDI.IndexOf("ORDERS")
' Start at that position and extract ORDERS + 5 characters = 11 characters in total.'
Dim ordersData = EDI.SubString(foundPosition, 11)

' Find the position where BGM is in the string.'
Dim foundPosition2 = EDI.IndexOf("BGM")
' Start at that position and extract BGM + 5 characters = 8 characters in total.'
Dim bgmData = EDI.SubString(foundPosition2, 8)

' Construct the CVS data.'
Dim cvsData = ordersData & "," & bgmData
```

Comment: Hello Egrunin and Santi, thank you very much for your ideas. It was very very helpful. I really like the straight forward approach from Santi. Thank you! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my IDE here, but something like this will work:

```
dim EDI as string = "UNH+RAM6957+ORDERS:D:96A:UN:EGC103'BGM+38G::ZEW+REQEST6957+9'DTM+Z05:0:805'DTM+137:20100930154"

dim result as string = KeywordPlus(EDI, "ORDER", 5) + "," _
    + KeywordPlus(EDI, "BGM", 5)

function KeywordPlus(s as string, keyword as string, length as integer) as string
    dim index as integer = s.IndexOf(keyword)
    if index = -1 then return ""
    return s.substring(index, keyword.length + length)
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

for the interrested people among us, I have put the code together, and created
a CSV file out of it. Maybe it can be helpful to others...

```
                 If EDI.Contains("LOC") Then
                    Dim foundPosition1 = EDI.IndexOf("LOC")
                    ' Start at that position and extract ORDERS + 5 characters = 11 characters in total.'
                    Dim locData = EDI.Substring(foundPosition1, 11)
                    'Console.WriteLine(locData)

                    Dim FoundPosition2 = EDI.IndexOf("QTY")
                    Dim qtyData = EDI.Substring(FoundPosition2, 11)
                    'Console.WriteLine(qtyData)

                    ' Construct the CSV data.
                    Dim csvData = locData & "," & qtyData
                    'Console.WriteLine(csvData)

                    ' Creating the CSV File.
                    Dim csvFile As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Test.csv"
                    Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)

                    outFile.WriteLine(csvData)
                    outFile.Close()
                    Console.WriteLine(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(csvFile))
                End IF
```

Have fun!